# Шифр Виженера(не работает)

Tags: c++, шифрование

решил сделать сам Шифратор/Дешифратор Виженера, но столкнулся с какой-то не понятной проблемой:

```
// Шифратор и дешифратор шифра Виженера.
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
#define e endl
using namespace std;
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    string x, y, z;
    int a, b, c;    
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
    short int r = 33;
    string alf = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
    int d = 0;

    for( int i = 0 ; i < x.size() ; i++ )
    {
        // cout << 124;
        if( d > y.size()) 
        {
            d = 0;
        }
        //cout << 124;
        b = 0;
        while( x[i] != alf[b] )
        {
            b++;
        }
        // cout << 124;
        c = 0;
        while( y[d] != alf[c] )
        {
            c++;
        }
        //cout << 124;
        a = b + c;
        if( a > r )
        {
            a = a - r;          
        }
        //cout << 124;
        z += alf[a];
        //cout << 124;
        d++;
        //cout << 124;
    }
    cout << z;
    return 0;

}
```

После ввода двух слов( x - слово которое шифруется, y - ключ шифрования ) у меня крашится программа. После того как я посмотрел после какого действия у меня не выводит "124", я понял, что это после этого фрагмента:

```
c = 0;
    while( y[d] != alf[c] )
    {
        c++;
    }
```

Не вижу ничего такого, что могло поломать программу, может быть вы увидите.
p.s. Если не сложно, можете кинуть наработки по абсолютно любым шифраторам/дешифраторам на C++, буду благодарен...
UPD: Проблема не в этом цикле, а чём то другом...

Comment: Какие значения у переменных `y`, `alf`, `d` и `c` в момент падения? Почему отсутствует проверки на выход за пределы массивов?

Comment: Ещё пара моментов: `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");` - Russian скорее всего неверное значение; `if( a > r )` - когда a==33 условие не выполнится, но `alf[a]` уже выйдет за пределы строки алфавита.

Comment: VTT, обращаюсь к вам(Просто не знаю как цитировать на этом форуме)
Что значит выражение:"В момент падения"

Comment: @Lyth, setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");  работает верно, с этим точно проблем нет(Копирую из предыдущих программ)
  if( a >= r )
  {
   a = a - r;   
  }
Все равно прога ломается( Ломается после действия  z += alf[a]; )

Comment: Сами же написали "программа крашится". Вот про значения переменных в этот момент я и спрашиваю. И на какой конкретно строке она падает? на `y[d] != alf[c]`?

Comment: @VTT, ааа, падение - краш программы, сейчас проверю посмотрю...

Comment: В общем получается такие "Интереснейшие" выходные данные:
y = ?????
alf = (Ну тут правильно, весь алфавит вывел)
d = 0(Верно)
c = 3417(Заходите в бесконечный цикл)
Все попробовал, ничего не получается :(
Может сама суть алгоритма не правильна?

Comment: Скорее всего, циклы `while( x[i] != alf[b] )` и `while( y[d] != alf[c] )` не заканчиваются корректно. Причина в том, что с консоли Вы вводите  русские буквы в Unicode (если я правильно понимаю), а программа работает с cp1251. Кроме этого, Вы вводите строки x и y капсом? Вы гарантируете, что в них нет латинских символов, цифр, знаков препинания и других символов, есть только заглавные русские? Приведите пожалуйста и примеры ввода данных к программе. И в программе явно не хватает проверки корректности входных данных + дополнительного условия в циклах для выхода (типа на случай b или c > 33).

Comment: То есть, прога должна работать только на латинице? А на рус. яз. нельзя такое проделать? Спец. функция к примеру...

Comment: Конечно, можно и на русском. Просто Вам надо разобраться с кодировками и все согласовать (код программы и ввод данных).

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решается, если консоли явно указать кодировку для ввода символов `SetConsoleCP(1251);`. Но это не отменяет необходимость проверять входные данные и проверять счетчики `b` и `c` на допустимость значений.

```
// Шифратор и дешифратор шифра Виженера.
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
#include <windows.h>

#define e endl
using namespace std;
int main(){

    SetConsoleCP(1251);     
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    string x, y, z;
    int a, b, c;    
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;

    // на всякий случай проверяем значения:
    cout << "x = " << x << "\n";
    cout << "y = " << y << "\n";

    short int r = 33;
    string alf = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
    int d = 0;

    for( int i = 0 ; i < x.size() ; i++ )
    {
        // cout << 124;
        if( d > y.size()) 
        {
            d = 0;
        }
        //cout << 124;
        b = 0;
        while( x[i] != alf[b] )
        {
            b++;
        }
        // cout << 124;
        c = 0;
        while( y[d] != alf[c] )
        {
            c++;
        }
        //cout << 124;

        // на всякий случай проверяем значения:
        cout << "b = " << b << "\n";
        cout << "c = " << c << "\n";

        a = b + c;
        if( a > r )
        {
            a = a - r;          
        }
        //cout << 124;
        z += alf[a];
        //cout << 124;
        d++;
        //cout << 124;
    }
    cout << z;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Ничего не сработало на русском, поставил латынь, все работает корректно, но как сделать на русском языке?

Comment: @ArtemAkimov, Я же написал, что проблема в несоответствии входной кодировки консоли и кодировки в программе. Вы какую кодировку в программе используете? Модную UTF-8? Или Unicode от MS (кажется там UTF-16LE)? Проще всего для Вашей задачи было бы оставаться в рамках однобайтовых кодировок. Или разбирайтесь, как правильно пользоваться многобайтовыми кодировками...